# Use android cam as a video input in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, android-camera

I'm trying to access my Android cellphone camera as an external cam on Image Acquisition Toolbox. I've read some topics about image acquisition using URL to access camera, but none of them used as a live video input and can't access as a camera in toolbox.

Is there any way to access cam with `imaqhwinfo` and `videoinput` commands?

Comment: You're more likely to get a quick, helpful response if you put here some of the code you've already tried and had specific problems with...